# "whom...from" vs "from whom..." - positions of interrogative pronoun and preposition

Tags: prepositions, word-order, pronouns

Are both following sentences correct? If so, which one is more usual?

- Whom did the attacks come from?
- From whom did the attacks come?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to phrase it that way? How are you going to use this sentence - writing/speaking? Give us more details so people here can properly understand what you are looking for. The way it is now, without context, raises the question in my mind - why not just say "Who attacked?" May be that is not what you want, but you have make that clear in your question.

Comment: *Whom did the attacks come from?* is an awkward mixture of English in its 'Sunday best' ("Whom") and informal English (ending a sentence with a preposition). If you're going to end the sentence that way then why not start it with 'Who'? 'Who did the attacks come from?' is imperfect English but at least it's consistent. *From whom did the attacks come?* is perfect, formal English, but a little old fashioned nowadays. Like AIQ I wonder why you want to phrase it as you have. I would prefer to ask, 'Who attacked [me/you/them or whoever]?'.

Comment: I got both sentences as possible translations of a sentence in another language to English in an language learning tool and I want to confirm if any of them is usual.